# Why was the "accepting user input" question received on the site while being off-topic?

Tags: support, tags, site-scope, comments, close-reasons

**Disclaimer**: Don't flag broad, as it's all very interconnected and can be answered well in one post. One shouldn't repeat the whole story again and again. Also, I had exams so had avoided discussions back then but kept checking the site.

- [accepting input from a user in python](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/369996/accepting-input-from-a-user-in-python/370003#370003)

was a question on 13th Sept with missing code formatting and to guide OP in case they post it somewhere, I edited it and added [script](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/script) as that is what we have for such questions. Then I left a comment suggesting SO, searching for related questions and reading help center, and asked the python version. This comment was deleted.

<sup>I'd love if someone could post the original comment as I forgot what it was.</sup>

Two answers were given, one claiming version problem, one about an alternative approach. I downvoted both.

To avoid serial/ revenge voting accusations:

- For nohillside's answer, it wasn't really a great answer, I am pretty sure some way or the other, people could get a file name with a custom prompt and suggesting newer version for it didn't seem appropriate to me.
- For jmh's answer, I am discussing it in the comments, if the answer or the original question doesn't get deleted. I tried OP's code on python3 and it worked, their code worked too. There's no way to tell if it fixes what the problem in their setup is. Also, it should be code format, not quote, generally.

Then the post was flagged by Mark (and maybe by some other <3k rep user) and nohillside put it on hold 2 days ago, after deleting their own answer. (oh! that explains a recent +1).

My queries are:

1. Did I go wrong by adding the script tag?
2. Why was the comment deleted which IIRC didn't contain any objectionable content? It was better to have it since it was accusing the post of being off-topic which might get seen by some other moderator if it is a borderline case.  It could have been edited too by the mod.
3. Why did nohillside as a mod answer a potentially off-topic question?
4. Didn't my comment matter while Mark's close vote did, for the same goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python questions are a borderline case IMHO. Looking at the strict wording of the on-topic/off-topic pages it's probably off-topic, OTOH it's used in a lot of scripting-type scenarios (for which people tended to use bash previously) which makes them kind of on-topic (still IMHO, we didn't have a community discussion on this). That's why I tend to answer small, not directly programming/design/algorithm related python questions instead of bouncing them to SO.

The community thought otherwise in this case (as shown in the votes to close) so I had to come back to that decision this time :-)

As for the `script` tag: The tag definition reads

> A collection of commands that may be from a CLI Shell, or programming language such as AppleScript, which are executed in order with limited iteration, usually as a way of automating actions or events

which leaves quite lot of room for interpretation (and improvement) actually. Strictly speaking it's probably not really applicable to questions like the one mentioned above, but then I doubt the tag makes a lot of sense anyway.

PS: Regarding your comment: Telling people, especially newjoiners, to post on SO usually results in duplicated posts on both sites. If a migration is required, vote to close accordingly.

Comment: I forgot that I myself had two answers on this. https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A313842+python+script+%5Bterminal%5D ^^' . Also hinting about *Did I go wrong by adding the script tag?* completes the answer.